# asp.net tooltip on textbox focus

Tags: asp.net, textbox

Hi I want to set a tool tip whenever a user clicks on the textbox, I haven't started anything programatically yet since I don't have any idea on how to achieve this, can you please help me?

In the picture, it is shown that a tooltip is shown whenever a user clicks the textbox and is gone when off focus..

[image]

Comment: use `ToolTip` attribute

Comment: See http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/tooltips-scripts-50-scripts-with-ajax-javascripts-css-tutorials/

Comment: the TollTip attribute is not working though

Answer (score 0):

You can use css or javascript to be able to style your tooltips.
Take a look at http://csstooltip.com/. If you want your site to be compatible with old browsers you'd have to use javascript. If you're using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), there are many available plugins to use with it. Just google "jquery tooltip".